# tkinter Listbox error when used as class object

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to create a class of `Listbox` object so that it can be used anywhere it is needed but it throws `TypeError` error, here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class cls_list(tk.Listbox):
    def __init__(self, master, callfrom):
        tk.Listbox.__init__(self, master, callfrom)

        callfrom.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.show_list)

    def show_list(self, event):
        x = callfrom.winfo_x()
        y = callfrom.winfo_y()
        h = callfrom.winfo_height()
        self.place(x = x, y = y+h)
        self.insert('end',*('Banana','Orange','Apple','Mango'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    ent = tk.Entry(root, font = (None, 20))
    lst = cls_list(root, ent)
    ent.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Can someone correct me what I am doing wrong?
Here is complete Exception occurred:

```
  File "/home/waheed/env_pinpoint/lib/python3.9/site-packages/test_listbox.py", line 5, in __init__
    tk.Listbox.__init__(self, master, callfrom)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3162, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'listbox', cnf, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2566, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2537, in _setup
    if 'name' in cnf:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1652, in cget
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'cget', '-' + key)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

This is what I have achieved so far.

```
import tkinter as tk

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('400x400')
    ent = tk.Entry(root, font = (None, 20))
    lst = tk.Listbox(root, font = (None, 20))
    ent.pack()
    ent.focus_set()

    def hide_list(event):
        index = int(lst.curselection()[0])
        val = lst.get(index)
        ent.delete(0,'end')
        ent.insert(0,val)
        lst.place_forget()

    def show_list(event):
        ent.update_idletasks()
        x = ent.winfo_x()
        y = ent.winfo_y()
        h = ent.winfo_height()
        lst.place(x = x, y = y+h)
        items = ['Banana','Orange','Apple','Mango']
        searchkey = ent.get()
        lst.delete(0, "end")
        for item in items:
            if searchkey.lower() in item.lower():
                lst.insert("end", item)
        n = lst.size()
        if n < 15:
            lst.config(height = 0)
        else:
            lst.config(height = 15)

    ent.bind("<KeyRelease>", show_list)
    lst.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", hide_list)
    root.mainloop()
```

And now I want to make it an object (separate class) for using in multiple scripts.

I hope now I have explained my question properly.

Comment: Remove `callfrom` from `tk.Listbox.__init__(self, master, callfrom)`.  But there are other issues in your code, for example `callfrom` is not defined inside `show_list()`.

Comment: Please include the error in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific error you're asking about is caused because you're passing `callfrom` here: `tk.Listbox.__init__(self, master, callfrom)`.

The listbox widget doesn't know what to do with `callfrom`, it expects the second positional argument to be a dictionary.

The proper way to initialize the class is without `callfrom`. You will need to save `callfrom` as an instance attribute if you need to use it outside of the `__init__`.

```
def __init__(self, master, callfrom):
    tk.Listbox.__init__(self, master)
    self.callfrom = callfrom
    ...


def show_list(self, event):
    x = self.callfrom.winfo_x()
    y = self.callfrom.winfo_y()
    h = self.callfrom.winfo_height()
    ...
```